# margin-top not working when clear:both used

Tags: html, css

As you can see from the code i'm using `clear:both` to allow me to place `#three` under `#one #two` but this seems to be stopping me from adding `margin-top` to `#three` is there a fix for this?

```
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
<div id="three" class="clearfix">
</div>

#one {
    float:left;
}

#two {
    float:right;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}

#three {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I went with the quickest, best answer for me. However you are all correct. Thank you again guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap #one and #two in a container with `overflow:hidden;`, and you won't even need the clearfix.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/CFa9s/)

---

```
<div id="container">
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
</div>
<div id="three"></div>

#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#one {
    float:left;
}
#two {
    float:right;
}
#three {
    margin-top: 20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you may use

```
padding-top : 20px
```

or you may also technically use

```
position: relative;
top: 20px;
```

applied on `#three` div. Or even

```
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

applied on `#two` div. And even

```
 #two:after {
    content : "";
    clear   : both;
    display : block;
    height  : 20px; // or margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Just choose the option that fits best for your layout

Comment: adding `padding` may be an issue if any of these divs has a background color/image, but `position:relative;` surely do the trick ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `float:left;` to #three to fix your issue

Edit: Or follow Fabrizio and add padding if you don't want to float anything, but no need to use relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now change some code in you html and do this

```
<div style='overflow:hidden'>
  <div id="one">Left</div>
  <div id="two">Right</div>
</div>
<div id="three" class="clearfix">// your data </div>
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/XrWbYKkx)***

Answer (score 0):

This [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uJBK2/3/) should help you

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="one">
        a
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        b
    </div>
</div>

<div id="three">
    c
</div>
```

CSS

```
#one {
    float:left;
}    
#two {
    float:right;
}    
clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
.row{ overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red; }
#three {
    margin-top: 40px;  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply the `clear: both;` to the `#three` div.

Then it will be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uJBK2/

**EDIT**
Now I see you're just missing a point before clearfix. Nevermind.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't answer the question.